# xmlhttp streaming data to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, xmlhttprequest

So I have a php file and javascript file. The data between them I transfer usin xmlhttprequest.

something like that:

```
var xmlhttp;
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open('POST', 'index.php', true);

        var params = "st=3";
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
            {
                alert (xmlhttp.responseText);
                var str = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                ...


            }   
        }
        xmlhttp.send(params);
```

on php i have a function that do some actions with database and return the result to jquery. And actually everything work, but now I have a cycle in php that took strings of data from bd and I need to send it to jquery. So since I don't want to make a lot of work with arrays (i usually create json file and sent it back to jquery), I have a question - how can I make a some sort of streaming data.

```
//I know that mysql is not secure but code represented only as example
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM payment ORDER BY IDN, Date",$db);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM payment WHERE IDN='$IDN'",$db); 
if ($result)
{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
        // here do some streaming back to jquery where it will be, let say, simply alert on the screen                          

        }
    }
```

Comment: "php that took strings of data from `bd`"? what is bd?

Comment: "how can I make a some sort of streaming data" what is data?

Comment: bd is just data base it is just mistake, in second question you have a cycle while what take result from data base - let say in database you have 3 strings of data  name1, name2 and number  : <br> alex mike 3 <br> michael nik 6 <br> kaly nick 10  cycle took this string one by one, and it must sent to jquery. But since this can be a 100 string instad of creating a long json file, I thinking about sent string by string.